# Laravel Auth::guest() doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed authentication using

> php artisan make:auth

Before and after loggingin menu shows login and Register link appears even user has logged in. I checked the code below and I found it was correct, there may be problem in Auth::guest(). check the code below

```
@if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
```

[image]

I referred some of the questions and they have given some dirty fix. example below.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Actually what this fix does,is force user to login by showing login page.Actually when the user logged in it should hide and show the user name. When I click on home link, it hides and shows username.

Comment: so even when you sign in successfully it would never show you that the user has logged in ?

Comment: when I click home link it shows I'm logged in. 'localhost:8000/' this does't shows only login Register option in the nav bar

Comment: var_dump(Session::all()); what does it give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the view on the web middleware, use the following code.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```